# Write log from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When creating Jenkins pipelines or libraries which should be used in a pipeline it's often hard to debug code with the logging options provided. At the moment I'm logging with this:

```
node {
  ...
  sh "echo ${thingtoshow}"
}
```

The downside is that this it's not very powerful when it comes to Groovy/Java specific details - e.g. it wouldn't allow me to dump the contents of objects right away

It creates a mess in the actual logs:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ echo 'things'
things
```

So how could I write logs to just get a single line of log output within the Jenkins console?

---

Edit: Even though the code example doesn't show it, but this is particularly useful when developing shared [Groovy libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) for Jenkins pipelines

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use the `echo` stage:

```
node {
  echo "qwerty"
}
```

It results in two lines:

```
[Pipeline] echo
qwerty
```

Unfortunately it generates two lines, but as far as i know that is the shortest form.

Comment: Thanks (I'm blind) - This solves at least one of the two problems - less mess, but is still not equal to a proper logger.

Comment: What are you looking for in a proper logger? E.g. what is missing with  the `echo` step?

Comment: Well I'd expect to throw any object into the logger and it should print something useful, while `echo currentBuild` would leave me with a stackstrace

Comment: Aha okay, use `print` instead, it uses `toString()` of the object that you send in. Not 100% sure what is going on here, but it works exactly like `echo` but handles objects.

Answer (score 11):

You can also invoke core Java's Logger.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger('org.example.jobdsl')
logger.info('Hello from a Job DSL script!')
```

The above will give you an entry like this at `http://yourjenkinsurl/log/all`:

```
Jan 22, 2018 3:27:58 PM INFO org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod invoke
Hello from a Job DSL script!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a shared library, then you can accomplish this by some custom code to access the context logger, as shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56344662/3456137

Then you can print to the console log without an additional lines.