# Get console Logger (or TaskListener) from Pipeline script method

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

If I have a Pipeline script method in Pipeline script (`Jenkinsfile`), my Global Pipeline Library's `vars/` or in a `src/` class, how can obtain the `OutputStream` for the console log? I want to write *directly* to the console log.

I know I can `echo` or `println`, but for this purpose I need to write without the extra output that yields. I also need to be able to pass the `OutputStream` to something else.

I know I can call `TaskListener.getLogger()` if I can get the  `TaskListener` (really `hudson.util.StreamTaskListener`) instance, but how?

I tried:

- I've looked into `manager.listener.logger` (from the groovy postbuild plugin) and in the early-build context I'm calling from it doesn't yield an OutputStream that writes to the job's Console Log.

  ```
  echo "listener is a ${manager.listener} - ${manager.listener.getClass().getName()} from ${manager} and has a ${manager.listener.logger} of class ${manager.listener.logger.getClass().getName()}"
  ```

  prints

  ```
  listener is a hudson.util.LogTaskListener@420c55c4 - hudson.util.LogTaskListener from org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder$BadgeManager@58ac0c55 and has a java.io.PrintStream@715b9f99 of class java.io.PrintStream
  ```
- I know you can get it from a `StepContext` via `context.get(TaskListener.class)` but I'm not *in* a `Step`, I'm in a `CpsScript` (i.e. `WorkflowScript` i.e. `Jenkinsfile`).
- Finding it from a `CpsFlowExecution` obtained from the `DSL` instance registered as the `steps` script-property, but I couldn't work out how to discover the `TaskListener` that's passed to it when it's created

How is it this hard? What am I missing? There's so much indirect magic I find it incredibly hard to navigate the system.

BTW, I'm aware direct access is blocked by Script Security, but I can create `@Whitelisted` methods, and anything in a global library's `vars/` is always whitelisted anyway.

Comment: "I also need to be able to pass the OutputStream to something else" .. if you manage to do that, please explain how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the build object from the Jenkins root object:

```
def listener = Jenkins.get()
    .getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
    .getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER))
    .getListener()

def logger = listener.getLogger() as PrintStream

logger.println("Listener: ${listener} Logger: ${logger}")
```

Result:

```
Listener: CloseableTaskListener[org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.log.BufferedBuildListener@6e9e6a16 / org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.log.BufferedBuildListener@6e9e6a16] Logger: java.io.PrintStream@423efc01
```

Answer (score 3):

After banging my head against this problem for a couple days I think I have a solution:

```
CpsThreadGroup.current().execution.owner.listener
```

It's ugly, and I don't know if it's correct or if there's a better way, but seems to work.

Comment: That's better than any hack I came up with, so thanks very much for the tip. Glad I'm not the only one intensely frustrated with this particular issue. I landed up giving up on my efforts to build a console filter that groups arbitrary ranges of console output into HTM5 `<detail><summary>...</summary>...</detail>` blocks via `withContext`: it became clear I'd have to write my own ConsoleAnnotation subclass and package in an extension, build it, etc, I could just bundle it as an @Extension in the global library because the code reading the console can't see that. It got too hard.

Comment: If I get time I want to return to it, since the current regexp-based console folding plugin does truly horrifying things to console log size and is not convenient for pipeline use.

Comment: I stumbled across another solution (untested) that seems to expose `StepContext.get()` to pipeline scripts: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withcontext-use-contextual-object-from-internal-apis-within-a-block

Comment: That tiny bullet point "context" .... ARGH. That does look promising, I'll look into it.

Comment: Jenkins 2.190.1. I get "No such property: CpsThreadGroup for class: groovy.lang.Binding". Should I upgrade some plugins? The above solution from @Mzzl is working for me.